Getting ValueError while trying to train GAN model
I am trying to train a GAN model to detect Diabetic retinopathic images but it's throwing error. Kindly help.
The images dataset is not empty I have tried looking into it
Error is:-
Epoch 1/50
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\asus\OneDrive\Desktop\project\DR-GAN\TrainModel.py", line 65, in <module>
    classifier.fit(X, Y, batch_size=32, epochs=50)
  File "C:\Users\asus\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\keras\src\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 122, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "C:\Users\asus\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\keras\src\backend\tensorflow\nn.py", line 553, in categorical_crossentropy
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Arguments `target` and `output` must have the same shape. Received: target.shape=(None, 3), output.shape=(None, 5)

The code for the train model file is:
import numpy as np
import imutils
import sys
import cv2
import os
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
from keras.models import model_from_json
from keras.layers import MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten
from keras.layers import Convolution2D
from keras.models import Sequential 

images = []
image_labels  = []
directory = 'dataset'
list_of_files = os.listdir(directory)
index = 0
for file in list_of_files:
    subfiles = os.listdir(directory+'/'+file)
    for sub in subfiles:
        path = directory+'/'+file+'/'+sub
        img = cv2.imread(path)
        #img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        if img is None:
          print('Wrong path:', path)
        else:
         img = cv2.resize(img, (32,32))
         im2arr = np.array(img)
         im2arr = im2arr.reshape(32,32,3)
         images.append(im2arr)
         image_labels.append(file)
    print(file)    

X = np.asarray(images)
Y = np.asarray(image_labels)
Y = to_categorical(Y)
img = X[20].reshape(32,32,3)
cv2.imshow('ff',cv2.resize(img,(250,250)))
cv2.waitKey(0)
print("shape == "+str(X.shape))
print("shape == "+str(Y.shape))
print(Y)
X = X.astype('float32')
X = X/255

np.save("model/img_data.txt",X)
np.save("model/img_label.txt",Y)

X = np.load('model/img_data.txt.npy')
Y = np.load('model/img_label.txt.npy')
print(Y)
img = X[20].reshape(32,32,3)
cv2.imshow('ff',cv2.resize(img,(250,250)))
cv2.waitKey(0)

classifier = Sequential() #alexnet transfer learning code here
classifier.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, input_shape = (32, 32, 3), activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2) , padding='same'))
classifier.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2) , padding='same'))
classifier.add(Flatten())
classifier.add(Dense(units = 128, activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(Dense(units = 5, activation = 'softmax'))
classifier.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])
classifier.fit(X, Y, batch_size=32, epochs=50)

I have tried changing dimensions but it isn't working I am not able to understand is it a version error or code error so to address the same kindly give the solutions.

The error refers to the shape mismatch while calculating the cross-entropy loss.
The last layer defined by you have 5 output units, while looking at the error, it feels like you have 3 distinct classes. Verify using len(set(Y))
classifier.add(Dense(units = 5, activation = 'softmax'))

Change the last softmax layer to
classifier.add(Dense(units = 3, activation = 'softmax'))

or maybe a little dynamic
classifier.add(Dense(units = len(set(Y)), activation = 'softmax'))

